# ERC-721 metadata doesn't show up for rinkeby but does show up for mumbai?

Tags: erc-721, meta-data

This is not rendering despite .tokenURI() returning the correct JSON blob.

URI Argument:

```
let metadata = {
    "description": "Tester", 
    "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Head_skull_anterior_view.jpg", 
    "name": "Ryan",
}
metadata = JSON.stringify(metadata)
```

.tokenURI() returns:

```
{"description":"Tester","image":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Head_skull_anterior_view.jpg","name":"Ryan"}
```

The Contract is very bare. 1 function that runs 2 functions: `_mint(address, id)` and `_setTokenURI(id, metadata)` from OpenZeppelin's ERC-21.sol and ERC271URIStorage.sol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a literal metadata document there. But you need a URI.

Please see the [data URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) which explains how to convert a literal document to a URI.

This is an intended and supported use case for `tokenURI` even if it looks a little weird.

Comment: Can you give some more detail? I've been trying to use `new URLSearchParams(metadata).toString()` + the schema [here](https://nftschool.dev/reference/metadata-schemas/#ethereum-and-evm-compatible-chains) and it's still not working

Comment: Please see here for an example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs

Answer (score 0):

To input plain JSON into an NFT as metadata, you must turn it into a URI by encoding the JSON in base64 and appending "data:application/json;base64," to the front of the base64 encoded string:

```
const base64 = require('base-64)
let uri = "data:application/json;base64," + base64.encode(jsonObject)
```

Comment: Please, can you add some text explaining your answer?